# reusable view with include tag and Ids

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a view hierarchy that consist with rows of similar layout structure that consist of two edit fields. So there is a  root LinearLayout (vertical) then 6 rows of Horizontal LinearLayout that each contain 2 EditText widgets. And I need to access these all EditTexts within the code.

As it is the same structure for each row , I thought to use a separate xml file call row.xml and include 6 of them using  , but the question is if I follow this how could I provide unique id for each EditText to access them within the code?

If this is not the right approach what would be the Android friendly way if doing this?

Comment: you dont need ids, just use getChildAt(idx)

Comment: I am not sure it is a reliable approach as it would hinder the UI flexibility

Comment: so use tags i.s.o. ids